# C# UnicodeCategory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm currently translating some C# code into JavaScript and I got stuck in one thing.
What is the equivalent in JavaScript for:

```
if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
{
  // Do something
}
```

I'm not being able to understand if we have this in JavaScript.

Comment: I doubt there is anything equivalent

Comment: Can you explain to me more or less the validation that is being made, since I never used this in the past?

Comment: There are [Unicode property escapes in regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)...

Comment: My answer would be better if there was a [mre] in the question, showing a value of `c` that causes the condition to be true and one that causes the condition to be false...

Comment: I think this code in C# is checking that the character doesn't have non spacing characters (like e.g. Spanish accents á, é, í, ó, ú). Check out this [How to remove accents/diacritics in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in) and [Remove accents/diacritics in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript). The second link would tell you how to detect those characters in different languages using Javascript.

Comment: @derloopkat the second link just fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As per @derloopkat help, I was able to solve this with the solution present in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript):

Thank you all for your help!

```
    const str = "Crème Brulée"
    str.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    > "Creme Brulee"
```

Answer (score -1):

The `UnicodeCategory` enumeration appears to map to the General Category listing of the Unicode Character Database. The [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes#General_categories) feature of JavaScript's regular expression engine appears able to map those General Categories.

For instance, the example given,

```
if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
{
  // Do something
}
```

would map to

```
if (!/\p{General_Category=Nonspacing_Mark}/.test(c)) {
  // Do something
}
```

But I believe it could be shortened to

```
if (!/\p{Nonspacing_Mark}/.test(c)) {
  // Do something
}
```